# Time of script execution [EDIT]

Tags: python, linux, bash

I read a serial port and send data to python, I want this chain to work for 10 seconds. The code below does not work:

```
sudo cat -v /dev/pts/2 | python3 bash_test.py 
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -9 $pid
```

[UPDATE]
e.g bash_test.py

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line,'\n')
```

Comment: cat needs an eof signal to exit.  The code is blocking on the cat command on the first line and never reaching the sleep command.

Comment: I see, but how can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timeout` :

```
sudo bash -c "cat -v /dev/pts/2 | timeout 10 python3 bash_test.py"
```

Command info:

```
NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]
```

Simple example for `timeout`:

```
timeout 3 sleep 10
```

The command here is `sleep 10` but `timeout` will kill it after 3 seconds.

Comment: @weider You should mark this answer since the solution he proposed solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding & sign after your sudo

```
sudo cat -v /dev/pts/2 | python3 bash_test.py &
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -9 $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code open a "sub-bash" environment where the actual command is running. In this way it can run in background. There could be some problem if you are using threads or multiprocessing in the python script.

```
(sudo cat -v /dev/pts/2 | python3 bash_test.py) &
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -9 $pid
```